# About create_line() math

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

everybody. The Tkinter library has a Canvas widget and class of Canvas has create_line() function to draw the line. So my question is - what math create_line() does use to fit point set in case when parameter of smooth is true. Is it least-squares procedure or something else?

Answer (score 0):

From [the official tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M136):

> smoothMethod must have one of the forms accepted by Tcl_GetBoolean or
>   a line smoothing method. Only true and raw are supported in the core
>   (with bezier being an alias for true), but more can be added at
>   runtime. If a boolean false value or empty string is given, no
>   smoothing is applied. A boolean truth value assumes true smoothing. If
>   the smoothing method is true, this indicates that the line should be
>   drawn as a curve, rendered as a set of quadratic splines: one spline
>   is drawn for the first and second line segments, one for the second
>   and third, and so on. Straight-line segments can be generated within a
>   curve by duplicating the end-points of the desired line segment. If
>   the smoothing method is raw, this indicates that the line should also
>   be drawn as a curve but where the list of coordinates is such that the
>   first coordinate pair (and every third coordinate pair thereafter) is
>   a knot point on a cubic Bezier curve, and the other coordinates are
>   control points on the cubic Bezier curve. Straight line segments can
>   be generated within a curve by making control points equal to their
>   neighbouring knot points. If the last point is a control point and not
>   a knot point, the point is repeated (one or two times) so that it also
>   becomes a knot point.